# django-axes installed, but axes.middleware module not available

Tags: python, django

I recently refactored a lot of code and wanted a clean environment, so I deleted and recreated the database schema, created a new venv, and installed dependencies from `pip3` one-by-one so I didn't have any superfluous packages left over from the old environment. I quickly installed half a dozen packages, then `migrate` passed. However, `runserver` complaines that `axes.middleware` isn't found (it is installed).

- I have django-axes 2.2.0 installed in my virtual environment (Edit: python 3.5, django 1.10).
- I verfied the installation was present with `pip3 freeze`, after
  uninstalling and reinstalling just to be sure. `django-axes==2.2.0`
- I have `axes` listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`
- I have `axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware` listed in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. **Note that if I comment out this line, django doesn't attempt to import `axes.middleware` and consequently `runserver` succeeds.**
- I can do `import axes; axes.get_version()` and also `from axes.decorators import watch_login` on the shell, so clearly axes is available to the environment.

What is going wrong here?

*Traceback from* `./manage.py runserver`:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f2d43a381e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/my_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "/webapps/my_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/webapps/my_app/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/webapps/my_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/webapps/my_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 153, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/webapps/my_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 56, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/webapps/my_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'axes.middleware'
```

Comment: What version of django do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of 2.0.0, django-axes has `default_app_config` so you can just use axes in INSTALLED_APPS without installing middleware. Hence, delete the relevant `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` line in settings.py

Comment: This is working for django 2.0.7 thank you very much, no middleware, only add axes to installed apps